# Rank of a 2 x 2 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

1. Prove that the rotation matrix is invertible.
2. Let
   $$
   \begin{pmatrix}
   \cos 2\pi t &  \cos \frac{\pi}{6}t\\
   \sin 2\pi t  &  \sin \frac{\pi}{6}t\\
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$

What is the rank of the last matrix for $0 \leq t < 12$ in particular for what values of t the matrix has rank 1.

I have prove $1$. and determine for which values the rotation matrix is not invertible but how can i prove $2$. Any hint will be appreciate it .Tahnxs.

Comment: Compute the determinant.

Comment: "I have prove 1. and determine for which values the rotation matrix is not invertible" --> Rotation matrix is always invertible (it has an inverse: a rotation in the opposite direction).

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\sin(a-b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)-\cos(a)\sin(b)$$ So $\det(A)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}6-2\pi\right)t$. Now think about the values which make it vanished. In fact, find out which values of $t$ make the rank $2$ and which ones make it $1$.

Answer (score 0):

How about taking the determinant, setting it to zero, and solving for $t$ to make the equation true?